# `steps_per_epoch` in google ai platform multi-worker distributed training

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-ai-platform, google-cloud-ai, distributed-training

I'm training model with tensorflow==2.7.0 distributively on gcloud ai platform.

I'm using `ParameterServerStrategy` strategy, with multiple workers.

One thing I'm confused, and couldn't find answer, is how to properly set number of steps each worker runs in one epoch.

consider code snippet:

```
def dataset_fn(input_context):
  ...

data_input = tf.keras.utils.experimental.DatasetCreator(dataset_fn=dataset_fn)

model.fit(
  data_input,
  epochs=...,
  steps_per_epoch=...)
```

is `steps_per_epoch`:

1. number of steps each worker runs

or

2. number of times master dispatches execution steps for workers?

Let's say dataset size is `1,000,000`, and `batch_size=100`, and there are `10` workers.
And in one epoch I want to process each instance in the dataset once, then

should I set `steps_per_epoch=1,000,000 / 100 = 10,000` or should I set it to `steps_per_epoch=1,000,000 / 100 / 10 = 1,000`?